# не определена переменная Python

Tags: python, python-3.7

```
import os
os.path.isdir('C:\ProgramData\Pk')
if True:
    pass
else:
    newpath = r'C:\ProgramData\Pk'# здесь ошибка
if not os.path.exists ( newpath ):
    os.makedirs ( newpath )
```

пишет что не определена переменная в чем ошибся и как исправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Блок `else` по очевидным причинам никогда не будет выполнен, а потому переменная `newpath` не будет объявлена и инициализирована.